# Alternative to Lock.tryLock() in Java 1.4

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

I would like to know if there is an existing alternative or how to implement the semantics of [java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock#tryLock()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#tryLock%28%29) before Java 5. That is the possibility to back off immediately if the lock is already held by another thread.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you want a solution for Java 2 (1.4) (Java 5 and 6 are already out of support)?

Comment: Well, out of curiosity too :) I in particular don't need it right now but I know there are plenty of Java 1.4 projects out there that could take advantage of this.

Comment: To clarify: I faced this problem in the past and I'm sure it can help others. Actually it has an upvote already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a `Lock` supporting a `tryLock` operation, you can’t use the intrinsic locking facility of Java. You have to implement your own `Lock` class which maintains the required state, i.e. an owner `Thread` and a counter and might use the intrinsic locking for its implementation of the thread-safe updates and blocking (there are not much alternatives in older Java versions).

A very simple implementation might look like this:

```
public final class Lock {
  private Thread owner;
  private int nestCount;

  public synchronized void lock() throws InterruptedException {
    for(;;) {
      if(tryLock()) return;
      wait();
    }
  }
  public synchronized boolean tryLock() {
    Thread me=Thread.currentThread();
    if(owner!=me) {
      if(nestCount!=0) return false;
      owner=me;
    }
    nestCount++;
    return true;
  }
  public synchronized void unlock() {
    if(owner!=Thread.currentThread())
      throw new IllegalMonitorStateException();
    if(--nestCount == 0) {
      owner=null;
      notify();
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the intrinsic lock of the `Lock` instance enforced by the `synchronized` methods is hold for a very short time only. The threads will either return immediately or go into the `wait` state which implies releasing the lock as well. Hence the `tryLock` will exhibit the desired behavior, though the Java 5 and newer equivalent will likely be more efficient. (The Java 5 and newer implementation of `synchronized` is more efficient as well…)