# Java optimized read/write a shared resource/memory location without Atomic API e.g. AtomicInteger

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

There is a shared resource and we need to perform read/write operations on it as per below:

1. When a write on resource is going on then no read should be allowed.
2. When a read is going on then no write should be allowed but multiple read threads should be able to read.

I have written code like mentioned below but the problem with this code is all reads will be blocked when a single read thread has acquired the lock. Further i am thinking to use a boolean flag e.g. canReadContinue. Now the first time when read acquires a lock i will flip this flag to true and if it is true then other threads should not try to acquire the lock.

```
class SharedResource {

    Lock writeLock

    public Object read() {
        writeLock.acquire()
        doRead()

    }

    public void write(Object toBeWritten) {
        writeLock.acquire()

        doWrite(toBeWritten)

        writeLock.release()
    }

}
```

Expected is multiple threads should be able to read when no write is going on.

UPDATED 1 :

public class SharedResource {

```
private Object writeLock = new Object();
private volatile boolean canReadContinue;
private volatile int readCount;

public void write(Object newState) throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized (writeLock) {
        // To make sure no read is going on
        while (readCount > 0) {
            wait();
        }
        System.out.println("Write thread has the lock.");
        doWrite(newState);
    }
}

public Object read() {
    if(canReadContinue) {
        incrementCount();
    } else {
        synchronized (writeLock) {
            System.out.println("Read thread has the lock.");
            canReadContinue = true;
            incrementCount();
        }
    }
    Object result = doRead();
    decrementCount();
    if(readCount == 0) {
        // TODO - release lock and notify

    }

    return result;
}

private synchronized void incrementCount() {
    readCount++;
}

private synchronized void decrementCount() {
    readCount--;
}


private void doWrite(Object newState) {
    // do stuff
}

private Object doRead() {
    return "";
}
```

}

Now i need a mechanism to release the lock at line "// TODO - release lock and notify", any pointers how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Why not just use a [`ReadWriteLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Andy but idea is not to use or have minimal use of Java 5 and above concurrency api classes.

Comment: @user10916892 why is that? What is your target JDK version?

Comment: If it helps, there is a backport of java.util.concurrent for Java 1.3: http://backport-jsr166.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Thilo lets say JDK 1.4

Comment: Have two locks. Read lock and write lock.

Comment: @Thilo It's probably homework...

Comment: @c0der As long as both locks are *exclusive* locks, there's no benefit because readers would block other readers, which is not requested.

Comment: *lets say JDK 1.4* Why?!?! That was last updated in [2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history).  Java 8 is already five years old.

Comment: Without 1.5, you have to use `Object.wait` and `Object.notify`.  I don't want to write it out in an answer, because it's annoying :)

Comment: @JimmyB I mean have a mechanism where read locks only write. Write locks both.

Comment: @c0der You'd still need some shared ("read") lock for the multiple readers.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24022445/2711488) contains a JDK 1.4 compatible reentrant lock implementation. Take it as an exercise, to extend it to a read-write lock.

Comment: Your updated code is half-way there now. You must however make sure that checks of conditions, e.g. `if (canReadContinue)`, happen inside the same critical section as the action taken based on the condition. - Where is `canReadContinue` ever set to false? Also, `synchronized` implies a "memory barrier", so variables to which *all* accesses are protected via `synchronized` need not be `volatile`.

Comment: You also cannot call `obj.wait()` or `obj.notify()` if you don't hold the monitor on `obj`.

Comment: I suggest not calling the synchronization object `writeLock`. Rather think about it this way: The `SharedResource` (as a synchronization tool) has some internal state composed of one or more data fields, and accesses to those data fields, both by 'readers' and 'writers', need to be protected against illegal concurrent accesses via a single synchronization object.

Comment: @JimmyB thanks but still i need to have a way to release the lock at my will, not sure how to do that.

Comment: Can anyone please share some code ? I am not able to get it correct yet.

Comment: Hint: If a reader or writer thread cannot proceed due to being excluded by the lock, it has to `wait` until the lock is released. Each time a thread releases a lock, it *notifies* any/all *wait*ing threads that the lock's state has changed and those threads then re-check if they can proceed and either go `wait`ing again or acquire the lock and continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering on your updated code here is some skeleton for you to complete:

```
public class SharedResource {

  private final Object signal = new Object();
  private boolean writeLocked;
  private int readerCount;

  public void write(final Object newState) throws InterruptedException {

    this.acquireWriteLock();

    try {

      // Now we know that no read and no other write is going on.
      System.out.println("Write thread has the lock.");
      this.doWrite(newState);

    } finally {
      // make sure we release the lock in any case.
      this.realeaseWriteLock();
    }

  }

  private void acquireWriteLock() throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized (this.signal) {

      // Wait until no more readers *and* no writer holds the lock.

      // To do: Insert the condition we need to wait for:

      while (/* condition here! */ ) {
        // To do: Wait for the lock-holding thread(s) to signal that they released their lock(s).
      }

      this.writeLocked = true; // Let others know that the write lock has been taken.

    }
  }

  private void realeaseWriteLock() {
    synchronized (this.signal) {

      this.writeLocked = false;

      // To do: Notify any and all other waiting threads that we released the lock!

    }
  }

  public Object read() {

    // To be done...

  }

  private void acquireReadLock() throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized (this.signal) {

      // Wait until no *writer* holds the lock.
      // To do: Insert condition we need to wait for:

      while (/* condition here! */ ) {
         // To do: Wait for the lock-holding thread(s) to signal that they released their lock(s).

      }

      // Now we know that no writer holds the lock. Acquire (another) read lock:

      this.readerCount++;

    }
  }

  private void releaseReadLock() throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized (this.signal) {

      this.readerCount--;

      // To do: Notify any threads waiting (i.e. writer threads).

      // (In fact only *required* if there are *no* more readers now because that's the only condition any thread will wait on.)

    }
  }

  private void doWrite(final Object newState) {
    // do stuff
  }

  private Object doRead() {
    return "";
  }

}
```

The main point to understand may be that *every* attempt to take a lock may have to `wait`, and that every release of a lock should `notify` any (potential) waiting threads.

Comment: thanks a lot, your "the main point to ..." has cleared the way, i will mark it answered shortly after i am done a bit of experimenting. One question so lets say last reader thread is done reading and about to release the lock and in the mean time a new writer and reader thread comes in, so at this point both will compete to acquire the lock, correct ?

Comment: @user10916892 Correct.

Answer (score 5):

Hints:

- You need a mutex; e.g. a primitive object lock.
- You need a counter of the number of readers *currently* holding a logical read lock.
- You need a flag to say if a writer is holding a logical write lock.
- You hold the mutex if and only you are acquiring or releasing a logical lock.  Once you have acquired it, you release the mutex.
- You will need to use `wait` and `notify`.

Effectively you need to<sup>1</sup> implement a simplified version `ReadWriteLock`.

---

<sup>1 - ... for the purposes of your homework assignment.  In a real world program, you should simply *use* the existing `ReadWriteLock` class.</sup>

Comment: *implement a simplified version `ReadWriteLock`*  And that's not really trivial, even for a simplified version.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem

Comment: Did I say it was trivial?  :-)

Comment: @AndrewHenle I see nowhere in that homework the request to implement a fairness policy, deadlock detection/prevention, priority inheritance or means to prevent starvation of threads. So the task is not "trivial", but doable in ~20-50 lines of code.

Comment: @JimmyB The title uses the word "optimized":  **Java optimize read/write a shared resource ...**.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yeah, and I bet "optimized" means that it's supposed to be an "optimization" of the previous homework in that it now should allow multiple concurrent readers instead of full mutual exclusion.

Answer (score 0):

> Further i am thinking to use a boolean flag e.g. canReadContinue

You're on the right track. But remember that *any number* of threads could concurrently perform their *read* accesses and that the write access can only be done if *no* other thread is currently reading or writing.

So you need to keep track of how many readers are currently holding the lock, and every reader must make sure to release the lock when it's done. Only if & when 0 readers (and 0 writers) hold the lock, a writer may proceed; and only if & when 0 writers hold the lock, any reader may proceed.